# multithread communication in python3.6 freeze

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-multithreading

I'm trying to develop a multithread function in python 3.6 and sometime my code freeze. from my tests I think that the problem come from os.write() or os.read(), but I don't know why.

here is my code (I don't think that partialTransform() cause the freeze but I put it to understand the code):

```
def naiveTransform(netData,**kwargs):

        #parralelisable part
        def partialTransform(debut, fin) :
            for i in range(debut, fin) :
                j = 0
                #calcul of all the distances :
                while j < nbrPoint :
                    distance[j] = euclidianDistance(netData[i], netData[j])
                    j += 1

                #construction of the graph :
                j = 0
                del distance[i]
                while j < k :
                    nearest = min(distance, key=distance.get)
                    del distance[nearest]   #if k > 1 we don't want to get always the same point.
                    graph.append([i, nearest])
                    j += 1

            return graph



        k = kwargs.get('k', 1)  # valeur par défault à definir.
        nbrCore = kwargs.get('Core', 1)
        nbrPoint = len(netData)
        nbrPointCore = nbrPoint//nbrCore
        distance = dict()
        graph = []

        #pipes
        r = [-1]*nbrCore
        w = [-1]*nbrCore
        pid = [-1]*nbrCore

        for i in range(nbrCore):
            r[i], w[i] = os.pipe()

            try:
                pid[i] = os.fork()
            except OSError:
                exit("Could not create a child process\n")


            if pid[i] == 0:
                if i < nbrCore-1 :
                    g = partialTransform(i*nbrPointCore, (i+1)*nbrPointCore)
                else :
                    g = partialTransform(i*nbrPointCore, nbrPoint)  #to be sure that there is not a forgoten point.
                print("write in " + str(i))
                import sys
                print(sys.getsizeof(g))
                os.write(w[i], pickle.dumps(g))
                print("exit")
                exit()


        for i in range(nbrCore):
            print("waiting " + str(i))
            finished = os.waitpid(pid[i], 0)
            print("received")
            graph += pickle.loads(os.read(r[i], 250000000))

        return graph
```

When the argument k is superior or equal to 5 the code freeze after the

```
print(sys.getsizeof(g))
```

For my example case when k = 4 the size is of 33928 and for k = 5 the size is of 43040 so I don't think that it's the problem ?
The number of core used don't seem to have any influence on the freeze.

I'm still a beginner in python so it may be something obvious but I didn't find any similar problem on internet. Do you have any idea of what could cause theses freeze ?

Comment: Pipes have operating system buffers. When the write is larger than that size, the writer blocks while the reader consumes. If the writer blocks, `waitpid` doesn't return and you freeze.

Comment: You probably want the parent to read the pipe until it closes and then unpickle.

Comment: Consider changing this to a small, working example that demonstrates the problem. Then we could run it, edit it, and post a solution.

Comment: thanks, is there another way to send a big object to the parent or do I have to make a loop to write/read ?

Comment: Another option is to use a temporary file instead of a pipe. The operating system caches it so its still pretty fast.

Comment: perfect, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Pipes have limited size buffers and the child will block writing the pipe until the parent reads it. But the parent is waiting for the child to exit, so you hang. You can avoid the buffer limit by writing the object to a temporary file instead. The data will be in the operation system file cache when the parent reads so it will still be fast.

There is a trick in all this. The parent needs to convince libc to re-examine the file after the child writes it or the read will just be satisfied by its 0 length internal cache. You can do that with a `seek`.

```
import tempfile

def naiveTransform(netData,**kwargs):

        // *** code removed for example ***
        # files
        tmp = [tempfile.TemporaryFile() for _ in range(nbrCore)]
        pid = [-1]*nbrCore

        for i in range(nbrCore):
            try:
                pid[i] = os.fork()
            except OSError:
                exit("Could not create a child process\n")


            if pid[i] == 0:
                if i < nbrCore-1 :
                    g = partialTransform(i*nbrPointCore, (i+1)*nbrPointCore)
                else :
                    g = partialTransform(i*nbrPointCore, nbrPoint)  #to be sure that there is not a forgoten point.
                print("write in " + str(i))
                import sys
                print(sys.getsizeof(g))
                pickle.dump(g, tmp[i])
                tmp[i].close()
                print("exit")
                exit()

        for i in range(nbrCore):
            print("waiting " + str(i))
            finished = os.waitpid(pid[i], 0)
            print("received")
            # seek to get updated file content
            tmp[i].seek(0,2)
            tmp[i].seek(0)
            graph += pickle.load(tmp[i])

        return graph
```